# why does entity_delete_multiple use a cursor not a set?

Tags: quiz

I am getting a lot of hits on the quiz module on my site, several thousand a month.
And I am finding from user feedback that I need to delete the old tests (they are all under anonymous login) to keep the quiz performance acceptable.

The act of deleting several thousand sets of quiz results can be very tedious because you can't just delete them all, something overflows and it errors out, so i need to delete a few hundred at a time. (Although now i have moved hosting company that has improved a lot)

It seemed to me that the delete function was deleting data one at a time. When i checked the code it invokes "entity_delete_multiple" which apparently gets passed a result set, but then instead of deleting the set, it opens a cursor an deletes them one by one.  This seems so counter intuitive that there must be some good reason?

```
foreach ($ids as $id) {
  $info['deletion callback']($id);
}
```

Is there anywhere in the api set that can get passed a set of ids and them does the equivalent of 'delete from table name where id in (set)'?

TIA

Comment: Given the amount of operations that happen for a single entity delete which _aren’t_ a straight SQL delete, it’s surely got to be more efficient to delete them one by one. Don’t forget caches need to be cleared (and your cache might not be in the database, maybe it’s in a backend that doesn’t support batch deletes), hooks need to run, and metadata needs to be updated. It’s not just running x number of SQL deletes in a loop, it’s much more complicated than that

Comment: The process behind that is called batch. Batch processing means some bulk operation being triggered processing only a certain amount of actions at once before it starts the process again to perform the next chunk of actions. This is supposed to prevent exactly what you described has happened before: exceeding a time out, memory limit hits. Seems the delete multiple function has incorporated that somehow.

Comment: There's no batching going on in `entity_delete_multiple` @leymannx - the memory footprint is kept low by using the cursor, but you're still pretty much guaranteed timeouts unless you execute the code via CLI.

Comment: @Clive – Ah I see, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Thanks @Clive  for the explanation. I think I understand now. Its been years since I've coded and I've never coded for the web, and managing memory in this way was never an issue. I think the answer for my problem is to have a pre-processor that automatically loops through a restricted set until everything is done.  Could probably rig a macro to do that.